# Count number of checkins

Tags: android, ios, facebook, checkin

I'm building an application that needs to count the number of check-ins. I'm making a request to Page's information and using the "checkin" object to track the checkins change, this is correct way?

This number is increased if I make a checkin using Facebook's app for iPhone, but not when I use Facebook's app for Android. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.

Don't worry about the checkin issue you had on Android, there's a number of things it could be... from counts that are aggregated on a certain timeframe, or if you checked in from the same account on the same day, it might only count as 1, etc.

Comment: I still can't get a new check-in number from people using Android, in any page or place and at any time :(

Comment: Checkin counts are not available per OS. They're there, it just might take some time to show up. Not every checkin will result in a +1. There are likely a few other factors. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Even when I'm testing with distinct and real users in iPhone and Android and the Android user made no check-in before trying it in the place I created? There is a way to get in touch with Facebook's developer support for this? Thanks for the help :)